# How to automate a dynamically changing web page using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to automate a web page since two weeks but I could not proceed further after 3rd page.

First I'm logging into login page by giving credentials and then I would click a link from 2nd page. Until this point I'm fine; but after that again I need to click another link from the 3rd page that I'm not able to, Even I was not able to read the proper `innerhtml` of that particular page. The `innerhtmal` varies from the source code of that page. Using the source code I have taken the id/name to get the element but no use. The problem I'm seeing is the DOCUMENT object is not taking the inner details of 3rd page. When I tried to print the links of that page it printed me some common links in that page which would be available in all the pages instead of printing all the links in that particular page. I guess this might happen because the page frame varies with respect to the FromDate & ToDate. Pardon me if I'm wrong. Do we need to change every time the "ie.document" object with respect to the navigation of web page? Because I think it sticks with the same when the page loaded 1st time.

## Below is my code:

```
Public Sub Test ()

    Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim frm As HTMLFrameElement
    Dim frms As HTMLElementCollection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim Login As Boolean

    strSQL = "https://website.com"   

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate strSQL

        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Set doc = ie.document

            Dim link As Object

        For Each link In doc.Links
            'Debug.Print link.innerText
             If link.innerText = "Click Here" Then
                link.Click
                Exit For
             End If
        Next link                   

           Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
```

Login_Pane:

```
    For Each link In doc.Links
       If link.innerText = "Leave & Attendance" Then
           'Debug.Print doc.body.innerHTML
           link.Click
           Login = True
          Exit For
         End If
    Next link

      If Login <> True Then
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        Application.SendKeys "<USERNAME>", True
        Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        Application.SendKeys "<PASSWORD>", True
        Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        GoTo Login_Pane
       End If

     Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

      Dim link As Object

    For Each link In doc.Links
        Debug.Print link.innerText 

        ' Above line code should print all the links in that page_
          _but unfortunatly it is not displaying as it is in the source code.
        ' instead printing half of the links which are commonly_ _available in all pages. 
        ' This page has three frames

    Next link


      End With
      'IE.Quit
End Sub
```

i'm unable to post the image of that page to make you understand more, Anyways i'll try my best.

when i use this below code i can only able to get the links from the upper portion of the page.

Set doc = ie.document
         Dim text As Object
          For Each text In doc.Links
            Debug.Print text.innerText
        Next text

Below to that portion of the page i have option to enter FromDate & ToDate, by giving dates to this textboxes i'll be able to see the details according to the dates (by default page displayes the details from 1st of the curent month to the current date of the month).

So, here i'm not getting the links/or other details. And i think the details of this sections are not stored in the ie.document object.
And this particular section alone has different URL from the main page.

Thanks.

Comment: *Every time* you navigate to a new page, there is a new document loaded, so you need to get a new reference to that new document.  So, re-run the line `Set doc = ie.document` whenever you exit the `Do While ie.Busy` loop

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your reply. by the way i'm not cleared by your comment. even i did try with the "Set doc = ie.document" line after the while loop.. but still i did not get anything.

Comment: Try @Jeanno's solution.  If that doesn't work then you'd need to post more details

Comment: An URL would have helped and/or more/ANY HTML. Trying to debug on just this = barely [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. For a page that dynamically loads you need to use `Application.Wait` (5 seconds or so) instead of `Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop`. The latter does not work if you have javascript being executed.
2. Using SendKeys should always be avoided as it is not robust.Inspect the element with a DOM explorer to get the ID or name.

Comment: Hi jeanno, as per your suggestion i replaced "Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop" with "Application.Wait". but after this change i'm getting the links from the previous page instead of the current page. it happens might be because it take the details before the page gets loaded. but actually here my concern is i'm already able to get the 3rd page links in the immediate window but the visible links all are the common ones.